# ordering items so no two adjacent ones are equal

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There are $n$ numbers, $a_1, a_2, ...., a_n$, which may contain repetitions. Under what conditions can they be arranged in such an order that no two same numbers are adjacent?

A necessary condition can be found easily.
Consider the answer to be $p_1, p_2, ...., p_n$

Also let $a_1$ be the number that occurs most often.

$p_1, p_2, p_3, ......, p_n$

$a_1, x,  a_2, x, ....$

If the count of $a_1 > \frac{n + 1}{2}$, it is easily proved that two same numbers will be adjacent to each other.
Now it seems that this necessary condition $a_1 \leq \frac{n + 1}{2}$, is also a sufficient condition.

How to prove sufficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_1$ occurs the most often then assume $a_{1} = a_{i_1} = ...=a_{i_k}$ with $i_1 = 1$ i.e. these are the numbers in the sequence which are $a_1$.

Put these on a row $a_{i_1} ... a_{i_k}$. Notice that this row has k+1 spaces where we may squeeze in new numbers between $a_{i_{j}}$ and $a_{i_{j+1}}$, at the end of the row and in the beggining. If we have less than $(n+1)/2$ of $a_1$ then we may atleast put one between each pair of elements. However as $a_1$ occurs the most (k times), we may put, in each space, at most one copy of each number. To make it even more clear. Let $a_{j_1}=...=a_{j_r}$ be all numbers in the sequence equal to some number which isn't $a_1$. Then $r\leq k$, and thus we may put $a_{j_1}$ between $a_{i_1}$ and $a_{i_2}$, $a_{j_2}$ between $a_{j_2}$ and $a_{j_3}$... and so on.